# sprite spawns 0,0 and won't update location

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, render

I've ran into quite an annoying problem and I was hoping someone among us might have knowledge about it that could possibly help.

The problem is that a sprite that's created to represent a player is stuck at it's spawn location. A spawn location which btw is not where I tell it to spawn and won't accept coordinates to spawn elsewhere, it will only spawn there which happens to be the top left corner of the screen. I had my program print out it's location continuously while running as well as the commands to change it's coordinates and it's receiving updated information as it should, the sprite just won't move. It acts the same way as if I have it bumping against an impenetrable wall.

relavent python/pygame code:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
     #This class represents the Player. 

    def __init__(self):
        #Set up the player on creation. 
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) 
        #draws on the sprite
        self.image = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png").convert_alpha() 
        # scales sprite based on resolution
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(width // 8,height // 7))

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y                 #sets initial spawn point  to x and y which are variables
        self.rect.x = x                 # set to the middle of the screen earlier in the program


    def update(self):
     # Update the player's position. #



        # Set the player's x,y coordinates to that of movex, movey
        self.rect.x = movex    #movex and movey are a means for changing x and y via player input
        self.rect.y = movey
```

.... calling the player class.....

```
player = Player()  #creates the player sprite that gets manipulated via the player class
player_list.add(player) #adds the new player to both lists to aid in tracking and updating
all_sprites_list.add(player)
```

......mean while inside the game function....

```
all_sprites_list.update()  #forces all sprites within the list to refer to their class's update          function

all_sprites_list.draw(screen) #auto magically draws all the new sprites

pygame.display.flip()   #actually renders the updated imagery for entire program.
```

That should be anything relevant to the sprite in question. I of course can provide further information if it's requested, I just didn't want to post massive blocks of code in here as it would probably scare people away. :p

Edit: the x and y are initially set as global variables that are height//2 and width//2 with height and width being used for resolution

movey and movex are globally set to 0 but update while the game runs through the game function loop.
example code with movey,movex:

```
if event.type == KEYDOWN:  #ship movement
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                movex=-6
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                movex=+6
            if event.key ==K_UP:
                movey=-6
            if event.key ==K_DOWN:
                movey=+6
            if event.key == K_a:
                movex=-6
            if event.key == K_d:
                movex=+6
            if event.key ==K_w:
                movey=-6
            if event.key ==K_s:
                movey=+6
x += movex
y +=movey
```

**UPDATE!!!!!!**

```
self.rect.x = movex    #movex and movey are a means for changing x and y via player input
self.rect.y = movey
```

this line simply needed to be:

```
self.rect.x += movex    #movex and movey are a means for changing x and y via player input
self.rect.y += movey
```

the addition of the plus before the equal sign changes self.rect.(x,y) values by the addition of movey,movex instead of repeatedly assigning them to thier their values.

Comment: Where are `x`, `y`, `movex`, and `movey` coming from? Those are certainly relevant.

Comment: The top left of the sprite spawns at 0,0 it seems which should be the default location. So the question then becomes, why does it ignore my self.rect.y/x statements and spawn there and then refuse the updated positions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the variables you are using (x and y): Do the same thing for the movex,movey

```
def __init__(self,x,y):
        #Set up the player on creation. 
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) 
        #draws on the sprite
        self.image = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png").convert_alpha() 
        # scales sprite based on resolution
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(width // 8,height // 7))

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y                 #sets initial spawn point  to x and y which are variables
        self.rect.x = x
```